# Why Javascript docs define function's parameter as a nested array in syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, ecmascript-6, documentation

I don't know how to ask this question, but while i'm studying documentation of Javascript or Node.js they are defining syntax something like this.

> var new_array = old_array.concat(value1[, value2[, ...[, valueN]]])

here all the parameters(`value1[, value2[, ...[, valueN]]]`) are defined as a nested array.

what actually it means, and

why not they are just defining something like this.

> var new_array = old_array.concat(...values)

OR

> var new_array = old_array.concat(valueList)

Comment: Any optional parameters are defined using comma `,` and square bracket `[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with arrays (except that your example is taken from the documentation of a method on the array type). The square bracket means an **optional argument** and this is a convention used in most programming languages and tools. For example, the help for the `ls` command:

`usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]`

... or `cp`:

```
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
```

Your example means that the function takes at least one argument and more arguments can be added separated by a comma. According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) these values can be *Arrays and/or values to concatenate into a new array*. So, each `valueN` can be an array or a value to add to the returned array.

The reason not to use the `...` notation is probably because the square brackets have been used for decades and are widespread, so readers will be familiar with the syntax no matter what the subject is.